# Example of non-extremum estimator

Tags: estimators, mathematical-statistics

Most of the classical estimator which are known , like LS, GMM, MLE, LAD, etc all can be classified as [Extremum Estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremum_estimator).  I was thinking for an example of an estimator which does not belong to this class.

Would it be correct if we say this estimator would be a Z-estimator and does not belong to the class of M-estimators?